# escape whole string in Java

Tags: java, string, escaping

I have this following code which gives me error of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 5
```

Now I know that what is causing the error, actually its a string which has two question marks inside it in the form of ?x,?y and as u can see in the code I have escaped the first one but the one in second last gives the error. how do I also escape this character which is in the middle of a string and i can not do it manually.

```
for(int j=0;j<table_update[0].length;j++)
            {
                 String replace_text=table_update[i][j];
                 System.out.println(replace_text);
                 String new_str;
                 new_str=replace_text.replaceAll("\\"+t_match,t_replace);      
                 table_update[i][j]=new_str;
                 System.out.println(table_update[i][j]);
                 line();

            }
```

is there any other method expcet using

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
```

for the said problem? and if org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils; is the only solution is it supported by android?

Comment: Looks lke you have an `(` in t_match, what is a Special character in regex. You have to escape it.

Comment: this is the complete error i get Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 5 \?x,?y) with an arrow down the y

Comment: Why aren't you using `replace` instead of `replaceAll` if you don't want the search string to be a regex?

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan you have to escape the `)`